# Codenameone/ Java: Adding Jars into Project

Tags: java, encryption, codenameone

I have tried to add 'rt.jar' and 'bouncycastle-jce-jdk13-112.jar' into my codename one project.

But it yields me error (The sample):

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/accessibility/AccessibleContext"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1061)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)
```

Anyone could solved this?

Comment: Don't know what "codenameone" is, but normally `rt.jar` is the standard Java APIs, and the JVM takes care of loading that itself; trying to load `rt.jar` yourself is likely to lead to all kinds of trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add JAR's directly to a Codename One project since the translation process needs to work with bytecode that was compiled in a particular way. Codename One has library project support that compiles sources in a way Codename One can work with and also provides native library integration.

Comment: but codenameone project does not support java.security.Security right? There's no ways to utilize the native java encryption lib?

Comment: No, it doesn't exist on some of the devices